# Conditional rendering multiple statements

Tags: reactjs, conditional-statements

In the following code, when the user clicks the submit button it's supposed to update and log "Hi". I tried using `&&` operator to do two different tasks.

```
type === "text" ? 
setTodos(updatedText) &&
console.log("HI") 
:
console.log(event.target)   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dispatch functions (like `setTodos`) do not return a value.

`expression1 && expression2` will resolve to `expression1` if `expression1` is falsey, and will not evaluate `expression2`. That's why `HI` isn't being logged.

Since you're not using the result as an *expression*, but you're just intending to run some *statements* (run `setTodos` and log stuff to the console), the conditional operator is not the right choice here. Use `if`/`else` instead:

```
if (type === 'text') {
  setTodos(updatedText);
  console.log("HI");
} else {
  console.log(event.target)  
}
```

It would be technically possible to write it as one large expression with the comma operator, but please don't:

```
type === "text"
  ? (setTodos(updatedText), console.log("HI"))
  : console.log(event.target);
```

Comment: I tried this but it allows runs the first statement(`setTodos`) and does not log

Comment: Oops, need to remove the `&&`

Comment: Still does not show up, even when I switch to log first then `setTodos`